# jax-rs url inside an ejb module

Tags: ejb, jax-rs

I created a tutorial that incorporates various components of J2EE in them.  The app is an `ear` module that has an `ejb` project and a web project.

the project structure is

```
john-app
    john-ear
    john-ejb
    john-web
```

the `ejb` project has a couple `dao` that perform basic crud operations using `jpa`. I'm trying to learn/understand `jax-rs` to  gain a better understanding of json and handling json objects.  the project is loosly based on
this project:

```
http://www.developer.com/java/creating-restful-web-services-with-jax-rs.html
```

so, i created my `BookResource` here and made it a `stateless` ejb. i have everything compiling and deploying without any obvious errors - other parts of the app work (the jpa stuff) but i can't get the `jax-rs` stuff to
work.  i have a couple of"Books" that I created in my database and am wanting to test this by making a rest call through the browser.

so i deploy my .`ear` file in `wildfly` (v10) with no obvious errors, I see JNDI mappings for my `EJB`'s...etc

initially, i'd like to be able to test this through my browser, but am not certain what url to use -- the class i have extending `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` has an application path of `/rest` and my
`BookResource` has a path of `/library`, and for getting all books from the library, the sub-resource is books. I've tried every combination of the url below,

```
 http://localhost:8080/john-[app|ear|ejb|web]/rest/library/books
```

all to no avail. every call results in a `404 error`, and the only time i got ANYTHING is when i tried john-web combination, it threw some ugly exception in the browser. so the questions is with a rest service living inside an ejb module within an ear, what should the url be given the above information.  nothing i've tried
seems to work!??

I've not included any code samples to try and keep the explanation short -- i didn't want to include every java file in my little project, but can add anything as requested.

Thanks,

JG

Comment: what about creating different war module for rest only like john-web-service?

Comment: B'bek, I've thought about this.  I started to do this yesterday, but got tied up with house work.  I'll finish looking at it and let you know, hopefully by the weekend.

Comment: if u need any help, just let me know I will provide snippet of my code, I'm also working on this type of Module recently

Comment: Great and thanks.  I'm sure i'll have issues, just not sure what they'll be...  nothing ever works the first time for me!